# Find the area between $r = 1 - \sin θ$ and the circle $r = \sin θ$?

Tags: calculus

I have found the points of intersection but am not sure how I would split this into two integrals or why?

Comment: Here r and theta are from polar coordinates or the radius r is a function of theta?

Comment: I would draw a picture of both to see where you would have to split up the integral, if at all

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8rygln4pon), if you want the area between both we can do a little bit of symmetry to just get the area of one of the lobes, giving us

$$I = 2\cdot\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{\text{first lobe}} r^2\:d\theta = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\sin^2\theta\:d\theta + \int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(1-\sin\theta)^2\:d\theta$$

from looking at the bounds in the picture. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Start with a picture [image]

Then calculate the intersection in the first quadrant:
$$1-\sin\theta=\sin\theta$$
This yields $r=\sin\theta=1/2$. Then the area of one of the lobes(the first quadrant only) is $$A=\int_0^{1/2}r dr\int_{\arcsin r}^{\arcsin (1-r)}d\theta=\int_0^{1/2}r[\arcsin(1-r)-\arcsin r] dr$$
This is slightly longer to compute (integrate by parts), but not that hard. Get the answer and multiply by $2$, to get both lobes.

Answer (score 1):

We could use the polar integral formula $$A=\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} (r(\theta))^2\,d\theta$$ to find the area in between these two curves.

We have $r_1= 1-\sin \theta$ and $r_2=\sin\theta$. We need to find at what angles these two functions intersect. $$r_1=r_2$$ $$1-\sin\theta=\sin\theta$$ $$1=2\sin\theta$$  $$\frac{1}{2}=\sin\theta$$  $$\theta=\sin^{-1}\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)=\frac{\pi}{6}$$

These functions intersect again at $\theta=\frac{5\pi}{6}$ because that is when $\sin\theta=\frac{1}{2}$ on the interval $[0,\pi]$, which is how many radians we need to completely draw the circle once. That being said, if we were to continue with this interval, we would find the area inside the circle and outside of the cardioid, which is not what we want. We need to find some symmetry in this problem. After a bit of observation, we see that $r_1=r_2=0$ when the argument of $r_1$ is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and the argument of $r_2$ is $0$. Using this, we can now set up our integral. The circle will range from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{6}$ and the cardiod will range from $\frac{\pi}{6}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. We also need to multiply our integral by $2$ because of symmetry. $$\begin{align} A&=2\bigg[\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\sin^2\theta\,d\theta+\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (1-\sin\theta)^2\,d\theta\bigg]\\&\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\sin^2\theta\,d\theta+\displaystyle\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (1-\sin\theta)^2\,d\theta\\&= \frac{1}{24}(2\pi-3\sqrt{3})+\frac{1}{8}(4\pi-7\sqrt{3})\\&=\frac{1}{12}(7\pi-12\sqrt{3}) \end{align}$$

Answer (score -1):

Use polar coordinates $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$ to change your problem to Cartesian coordinates. Then you can use a geometrical approach, even integration, to find the number.

Edit: You could try making graphs on dependent variable $r$ for independent variable $\theta$ without going to Cartesian (since the equations are so simple).

Comment: I'm not saying you can't do this, but going to Cartesian coordinates makes this infinitely worse. Limacons and cardioids do not have nice geometric anything in rectangular coordinates.

Comment: The second one is just a circle. The first one I can't tell just by looking at but looks that can not be much worse. Have you tried taking that to cartesian already?

Comment: The first object is not a circle it is an object called a Limacon, I've already said this

Comment: Anyway your post is more suited for a comment, not an answer. Could you flesh it out?

Comment: It's not needed to do anything fancy honestly, look at my edited comment to solve with zero effort.

Comment: Calling something "zero effort" while simultaneously providing bare bones details is at best mildly annoying, at worst a little condescending to OP. If you feel OP has not provided enough details to post a full answer, then don't post a comment as an answer.

Comment: One of the curves is a circle and the other is a cardioid.